# Does AdventureWorks ASP.Net web project exist?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I know nopCommerce and dashCommerce quite well, but I so far have never found any open source shopping cart (including HumanResources and Vendors) bigger than the nopCommerce.

I'm wondering whether AdventureWorks database comes together with a web project or other UI projects as an open source. Or it just exists as a sample database only.

Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdventureWorks is purely database goodness. The closest you would come to to a ASP.Net web project with UI would be the samples delivered with Access 2010 like the "Assets web database". It does not compare well to dashCommerce or nopCommerce though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample Web UI (ASP.NET Web forms) available with the database samples download (2005 and 2008).  There is also a site dedicated to building out a real world example, but it doesn't look like they are sharing a code download: demo.componentone.com/ASPNET/AdventureWorks/

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems that ComponentOne only implemented for the front end. I could not find the sample Web UI (ASP.NET Web forms) for advanture work at codeplex. Could you please share the link?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Cycle StoreFront](http://msfteeprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008!Readme_Storefront&referringTitle=Home) retail application from Microsoft SQL server multi-technology-product-samples?

From the site: *The Storefront sample for the Adventure Works Cycles sample database in SQL Server demonstrates how to build a simple Internet retail application by using SQL Server, ADO.NET, and ASP.NET. *

In fact, this is one of the many [end-to-end samples](http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/#e2e) they have, including:

- [Microsoft End-to-End Samples](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTEEProdSamples)
- [Community End-to-End Samples Gallery (sponsored by DPE)](http://www.codeplex.com/SQLSrvE2E)